# Finding out the direction of the maximum shear stress in a 3d stress tensor

Tags: strength, shear

I came across a problem where I was asked to find out the **direction** of the **maximum principal stress** in a given **stress tensor** , with the help of **eigen vectors** I was able to **construct an equation** which has **three roots** ,the three roots are the **three principal stresses** , but I am confused about how i will be able to find out the **direction of the maximum principal stress** , kindly help me.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming  the following stress tensor:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}100,20,0\\20,0,20\\0,20,50\end{bmatrix}$$

you can find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors in octave/matlab

```
A = [100, 20 ,0 ;20 ,0,20; 0,20 ,50]
[k,l] = eig(A)
```

The printout is

```
k =

   0.169653  -0.132430  -0.976565
  -0.935341   0.290482  -0.201883
   0.310410   0.947672  -0.074586

l =

Diagonal Matrix

   -10.265         0         0
         0    56.130         0
         0         0   104.135
```

The principal stress are ordered from the smallest to the largest(algebraically)

So

| principal Stress | principal Stress $\sigma_i$ | principal direction $\vec{v}_i$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $\sigma_1$ | 104.135 | $ \begin{bmatrix} 0.169653 \\ -0.935341 \\0.310410\end{bmatrix}$ |
| $\sigma_2$ | 56.130 | $ \begin{bmatrix} -0.132430\\ 0.290482 \\0.947672\end{bmatrix}$ |
| $\sigma_3$ | -10.265 | $ \begin{bmatrix}-0.976565 \\ -0.201883\\ -0.074586 \end{bmatrix}$ |

The maximum shear stress exists on the plane at 45 degrees to the planes of the largest and the smallest principal stress.

The value of the max shear stress is $\frac{104.135 -( -10.265)}{2} $

The max shear stress direction is:

$$\frac{\vec{v}_1+\vec{v}_3}{\sqrt{2}}=  \begin{bmatrix} -0.4035 \\ -0.5686\\   0.1179 \end{bmatrix}$$

**NOTE**: I am a bit rusty, so if you find an error please point it out.

Comment: just to be sure about the solution , are you finding out the direction cosines for each of the principal stresses  as the principal directions

Comment: I am not using the direction cosines at all. That would require to define for each vector three values, which I find confusing. If you want to do it that way you can though.

Comment: i appreciate your attempt , but at this moment (I) need to basically pen down the solution for assessment , so direction cosines would be more comfortable . Thank you for the help.